# C++ list Function return List

Tags: c++, list, header

I have 2 Classes in `ssservice.h`:

```
class ssverbindungsdaten {
public:
    ssverbindungsdaten();
    ~ssverbindungsdaten();

    int id;
    string test;
};

class softswitch {
public:
    softswitch();
    ~softswitch();
    list<ssverbindungsdaten> holeAlleRohdaten();
};
```

My `ssservice.ccp`:

```
list<ssverbindungsdaten> softswitch::holeAlleRohdaten() {
    //ssverbindungsdaten * ssv = new ssverbindungsdaten;
    list<ssverbindungsdaten> *listTmp = new list<ssverbindungsdaten>;
    return *listTmp;
}
```

And my main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Starte ...";

    softswitch *ss = new softswitch;
    list<ssverbindungsdaten> *liSSVVerbinngsdaten = new list<ssverbindungsdaten>();
    liSSVVerbinngsdaten = ss->holeAlleRohdaten();
}
```

But there is an error in `main.cpp`:

```
cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::list<ssverbindungsdaten>’
  to ‘std::__cxx11::list<ssverbindungsdaten>*’
  in assignment
     liSSVVerbinngsdaten = ss->holeAlleRohdaten();
```

The list `holeAlleRohdaten` should be a lsit, containing all Classes `ssverbindungsdaten`.

That I can later loop trough the `liSSVVerbinngsdaten` in `main.cpp`, and get all Classes `ssverbindungsdaten` with the values `(int id, string test)`.

Why can't I just assing the List `liSSVVerbinngsdaten` to `ss->holeAlleRohdaten`?

Comment: You overuse pointers. And leak as a result. It's not *the* problem your are facing. But it's a major one, and closely related.

Comment: Do you come from a Java or C# background? In C++ you don't need to use `new` to create objects. Doing e.g. `list<ssverbindungsdaten> listTmp;` is enough.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought in cpp with the "new" the Objects will be stored in RAM? Cause the Object List contains later around 200 000 Entrys with ca 50 Attributes each Class.

Comment: You should really start coding in english and use best practices for your nomenclature! e.g. camel case. Also if you're giving away object ownership use shared pointers.

Comment: All object you create will be stored in *memory*. Exactly where that memory is, or if some is defined to be a stack and some to be a heap doesn't matter. Just stop using pointers so much, unless you *really* need it (and then use *smart pointers*), which you don't to anywhere here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, thanks! Really helpful.

Comment: @Flowkap Jepp, I know. I was just testing a little while. But I just changes all Names to CamelCase ones. :)

Comment: @Patrick Sorry but you should ALWAYS work by best practices. Why start with test code you want to rewrite again? There will be occasions where  test code quickly gets productive and so on. That is a bad habit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list<ssverbindungsdaten> *listTmp = new list<ssverbindungsdaten>;
```

The "new" keyword in c++ actually allocates a new pointer, so you are manually allocating a pointer to a list of ssverbindungsdaten objects.
If you want to create a default instance of the class or list just use

`list<ssverbindungen> listTmp;`

Edit: Also stop coding in german and uppercase your class names

Comment: Why uppercase my Class-Names?

Comment: I have them camel case now

Comment: @Patrick because classes always start with a capital letter and continue camel case. It's internationally accepted as best practice to do so. No matter what language.

Answer (score 1):

You should do what the others say about pointers, smart pointers, naming, ...

But your error is

```
liSSVVerbinngsdaten = ss->holeAlleRohdaten();
```

`liSSVVerbinngsdaten` is a pointer to a list and `ss->holeAlleRohdaten()` returns a list. You can fix your program by returning a pointer

ssservice.h:

```
class ssverbindungsdaten
{
public:
    ssverbindungsdaten();
    ~ssverbindungsdaten();

    int id;
    string test;

};

class softswitch{
public:
    softswitch();
    ~softswitch();
    list<ssverbindungsdaten>* holeAlleRohdaten();

};
```

ssservice.ccp:

```
list<ssverbindungsdaten>* softswitch::holeAlleRohdaten(){

    //ssverbindungsdaten * ssv = new ssverbindungsdaten;

    list<ssverbindungsdaten> *listTmp = new list<ssverbindungsdaten>;

    return listTmp;

}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //TODO: Mulithreading
    std::cout << "Starte ...";

    softswitch *ss = new softswitch;

    list<ssverbindungsdaten> *liSSVVerbinngsdaten = new list<ssverbindungsdaten>();

    delete liSSVVerbinngsdaten;
    liSSVVerbinngsdaten = ss->holeAlleRohdaten();

    delete softswitch;
    delete liSSVVerbinngsdaten;
    return 0;
}
```

This answer is only to understand the error. As the others said you should avoid raw pointers and use smart pointers. If you work with raw pointers you should remember that to every `new` belongs a `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

If you skip all the `new` and pointers, the code will be *a lot* simpler:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //TODO: Mulithreading
    std::cout << "Starte ...";

    softswitch ss;

    list<ssverbindungsdaten> liSSVVerbinngsdaten = ss.holeAlleRohdaten();

    return 0;
}
```

C++ is not at all like Java or C#. The `list` class will handle all the heap allocations internally. You don't have to do that.